# Add custom values to external binding (JAXB - MOXY implementation)

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, moxy

I want to marshal a Java-Object to XML.For this approach I am using JAXB Moxy with an external XML binding file.

Here is an example class which I want marshal to XML:

```
public class Customer {
  private String lastname;
  private String firstname;

  //getters and setters
}
```

With my external binding file I can access the values of this class, so that I get the following XML-output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<customer>
  <firstname>Tony</firstname>
  <lastname>Stark</lastname>
</customer>
```

Now I want to add a custom tag with a custom value which isn't specified in the java class. So for the above Customer class I want an XML output like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<customer>
  <firstname>Tony</firstname>
  <lastname>Stark</lastname>
  <birthdate>01.01.1990</birthdate>
</customer>
```

Birthdate isn't in the Customer-class and I don't want to add it there because this class is automaticaly generated by a script. My goal is to define birthdate with my custom value in the external binding file. Is this even possible with the JAXB MOXY implementation?
Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a way that you could leverage an `XmlAdapter` to do this:

**XmlAdapter (LastNameAdapter)**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class LastNameAdapter extends XmlAdapter<LastNameAdapter.AdaptedLastName, String> {

    @XmlType(propOrder={"lastname", "birthdate"})
    public static class AdaptedLastName {
        public String lastname;
        public String birthdate;
    }

    private String birthdate;

    public LastNameAdapter() {
    }

    public LastNameAdapter(String birthdate) {
        this.birthdate = birthdate;
    }

    @Override
    public String unmarshal(AdaptedLastName v) throws Exception {
        return v.lastname;
    }

    @Override
    public AdaptedLastName marshal(String v) throws Exception {
        AdaptedLastName adaptedLastName = new AdaptedLastName();
        adaptedLastName.lastname = v;
        adaptedLastName.birthdate = birthdate;
        return adaptedLastName;
    }

}
```

**External Metadata (oxm.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings
    xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    package-name="forum19641824">
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="Customer">
            <xml-root-element/>
            <xml-type prop-order="firstname lastname"/>
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-element java-attribute="firstname"/>
                <xml-element java-attribute="lastname" xml-path=".">
                    <xml-java-type-adapter value="forum19641824.LastNameAdapter"/>
                </xml-element>
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

**Demo**

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(1);
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.OXM_METADATA_SOURCE, "forum19641824/oxm.xml");
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {Customer.class}, properties);

        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setFirstname("Tony");
        customer.setLastname("Stark");

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setAdapter(new LastNameAdapter("01.01.1990"));
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(customer, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customer>
   <firstname>Tony</firstname>
   <lastname>Stark</lastname>
   <birthdate>01.01.1990</birthdate>
</customer>
```